# Исключения в python

Tags: python

Программа калькулятор,в которой нужно поставить исключения на ввод операций,чисел и деление на 0.Написал код с двумя исключениями,не могу понять,в чем ошибка.Помогите откорректировать.

```
while True:
    s = input("Знак (+,-,*,/): ")
    try:
        if s in ('+','-','*','/'):
    except ValueError:
        print("Неверный знак операции!")
        else:
            x = float(input("x="))
            y = float(input("y="))
            if s == '+':
                print("%.2f" % (x+y))
            elif s == '-':
                print("%.2f" % (x-y))
            elif s == '*':
                print("%.2f" % (x*y))
            elif s == '/':
                try:
                    if y == 0:
                except AssertionError:
                    print("Деление на 0")
                else:
                    print("%.2f" % (x/y))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def addition(x, y):
    return x + y


def subtraction(x, y):
    return x - y


def multiplication(x, y):
    return x * y


def division(x, y):
    return x / y


operations = {
    '+': addition,
    '-': subtraction,
    '*': multiplication,
    '/': division
}

while True:
    sign = input('Знак (+, -, *, /): ')
    if sign == 'exit':
        break
    try:
        operation = operations[sign]
        x = float(input('x = '))
        y = float(input('y = '))
        print('{0:.2f}'.format(operation(x, y)))
    except KeyError:
        print('Неверный знак операции!')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Деление на 0!')
    except ValueError:
        print('Не удалось преобразовать в число!')
```

Answer (score 0):

В блок `try` нужно помещать не проверку, а сам кусочек кода, в котором мы ожидаем потенциальную проблему. Проверка вообще не нужна - механизм отлова исключений их заменяет.

Кроме того, у вас путаница с тем, когда нужно выбрасывать исключение, а когда ловить его. Почитайте ещё, для чего вообще нужны исключения.

Ну и никогда ни в каком случае после строки, начинающейся с `if` не может идти строка с меньшим отступом.

Нужно примерно как-то так:

```
import operator


OPER_MAP = {
    '+': operator.add,
    '-': operator.sub,
    '*': operator.mul,
    '/': operator.truediv,
}


def calculator():
    s = input("Знак (+,-,*,/): ")
    if s not in OPER_MAP:
        raise ValueError()
    x = float(input("x="))
    y = float(input("y="))
    if s == '/' and y < 0:
        # Просто для примера.
        # На самом деле, такое исключение и так бы выбросилось
        # при попытке делить на ноль
        # и эту проверку можно вообще убрать
        raise ZeroDivisionError
    operation = OPER_MAP[s]
    print(operation(x, y))


while True:
    try:
        calculator()
    except ValueError:
        print("Такой арифметической операции не существует, попробуйте ещё раз")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Делить на ноль нельзя, попробуйте сначала")
```

(Код расcчитан на третий питон. Для второго, в частности, нужно truediv заменить на div)